# How can I get a passed parameters name in C# (with nameof)

Tags: c#, parameters, parameter-passing, nameof

This returns parameter. I want to get i_want_to_know_this so I don't have to press CTRL+C 8 times. (So I can loop with     `foreach (int parameter in items[])`    )

```
static void get_parameters_name(int parameter){
    // get the passed in parameter's name
    Console.WriteLine("this parameter is called: " + parameterName);
}
int i_want_to_know_this = 0;

get_parameters_name(i_want_to_know_this);
```

Comment: You can't, and you really shouldn't care anyway.

Comment: @DavidG You can from C# 10+, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/caller-argument-expression. But one shouldn't care.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I know, but OP asked for using `nameof`. The second part of my comment is far more relevant anwyay.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Tis smells like x-y.

Comment: @Fildor I'm trying to read out my 8 static settings in my program by their name and let the user modify them. But I get the vibe that I should just write the whole function and shouldn't care to automate this part.

Answer (score -1):

When you wrap it in a method, the parameter name is the name of the parameter in the method, not of what was passed in.  The following line will print "i_want_to_know_this".

```
Console.WriteLine($"This parameter is called {nameof(i_want_to_know_this)}");
```